# How to change names of `map2_df` outputs

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This is my code.

```
countries <- c("USA", "Canada", "UK", "Germany", "France")
country_data <- map(countries, ~ tibble(
  Country = .,
  Population = sample(1000000:10000000, 1000),
  GDP = sample(50000:500000, 1),
  LifeExpectancy = runif(1, 70, 85)
)) %>% set_names(countries)   

calculate_stats_1 <- function(df) {
  mean(df$Population)
}

calculate_stats_2 <- function(df) {
  median(df$GDP)
}

calculate_stats_3 <- function(df) {
  max(df$LifeExpectancy)
}

calculate_stats_4 <- function(df) {
  min(df$LifeExpectancy)
}

calculate_stats_5 <- function(df) {
  sd(df$Population)
}
```

Here I would like to have the output (columns name) being the function name and the country names but as an `map2_df` argument. Is it possible?

I've tried to use the `.names = {.y}_{.x}` but its not working.

```
# Use a função map2 para aplicar as funções às listas correspondentes
result <- map2_df(
  .x = country_data,
  .y = list(stat1 = calculate_stats_1, 
            stat2 = calculate_stats_2,
            stat3 = calculate_stats_3, 
            stat4 = calculate_stats_4,
            stat5 = calculate_stats_5),
  ~ .y(.x)
)

# Exiba o resultado
print(result)
```

The outputput should like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `imap` and `summarise` & `across`. `imap` is basically a `map2` where the second list is the name of the list (the `.y`).

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
country_data |> 
  imap(~.x |> summarise(
    across(Population, mean, .names = paste0("stat1_", .y)),
    across(GDP, median, .names = paste0("stat2_", .y)),
    across(LifeExpectancy, min, .names = paste0("stat3_", .y)),
    across(Population, max, .names = paste0("stat4_", .y)),
    )) |> 
  bind_cols()

# A tibble: 1 × 20
  stat1_USA stat2_USA stat3_USA stat4_USA stat1_Canada stat2_Canada stat3_Canada stat4_Canada stat1_UK stat2_UK stat3_UK
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  5531597.    196798      76.0   9993319     5481076.       252241         84.1      9963195 5547161.   292601     78.9
```